# What role does this function play in my code?

Tags: python

```
    # BMI calculator

name1 = "Fahad"
weight_kg1 = "40.8"
height_m1 = "1.7"

name2 = "Rardo"
weight_kg2 = "140"
height_m2 = "1.9"

name3 = "Billy"
weight_kg3 = "70"
height_m3 = "2.2"

bmi_calculator(name,height,weight):
BMI = height_kg *(height_m * * 2)
print(bmi:)
if bmi < 25
        return name + "is not over weight"
    else:
        return name + "is overweight"

result1 = "name1, height_m1, weight_kg1"
result2 = "name2, height_m2, weight_kg2"
result3 = "name1, height_m1, weight_kg3"
```

I do not know the role of the function "BMI Calculator" (Line 15) 
Nor do I understand the role of "result 1 = "name 1, ..........." (Which is above)

I would be much obliged if one could explain the role of these two in my code, and how the function connects back to my code.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't defined any functions in the code you showed.

Comment: your code is not well formed and will make it hard to get a good answer.

Comment: you want to *make* `bmi_calculator` a *function* 
-- prepend it with "def": `def bmi_calculator(name,height,weight):` then *further* indent all lines below it

Comment: The code is confusing. `bmi_calculateor` doesn't seems to play any role unless it changes some global variable, is `bmi` a global variable? And since there are return statements, I assume this part of a function, in which case, those three `result1 = ...` lines don't play any role. They will never be called since they are after return statements (embedded in full-coverage-logic `if-else`)

Comment: This "python" code is not well formed. I guess you have a `bmi_calculator()` function, but it is not well declared (it misses the `def`, and also the indentation is wrong). I believe it calculates de Body Mass Index, but I can't figure out what those `resultn` variables are for. I think there is more code where they are used.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, I clearly said, "Line 15". Besides, anybody who knows python can point out a function.

Comment: If you want us to tell you what it does, you have to show us how you define it. That's what I meant; `bmi_calculator` is not a builtin function and you haven't said anywhere if you are using a library. Therefore, we have absolutely no idea what the function does, so we can't help you.

Comment: Oh, I see. You forgot the `def` keyword. It's required to define a function.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for defining functions in python:

`def function_name(parameters):`

your function name is missing the **`def`** keyword to define it a function. Read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Pay close attention to how indentation is *consistent*, each statement is `4` spaces, how much you indent is optional *but be sure each indent is the same width*.

Other errors in your code are corrected below, note to remove quotation marks (`" "`) from numerical values:

```
# BMI calculator

name1 = "Fahad"
weight_kg1 = 40.8  # removed "" from all 
height_m1 = 1.7    # these weight/height values

name2 = "Rardo"
weight_kg2 = 140 
height_m2 = 1.9   

name3 = "Billy"
weight_kg3 = 70
height_m3 = 2.2

def bmi_calculator(name,height,weight):
    BMI = weight * (height ** 2)  # exponent is `**` not `* *`
    print(BMI)                    # this prints the numerical values from the line above (see output below)
    if BMI < 25:
        return name + "is not over weight"
    else:
        return name + "is overweight"


result1 = bmi_calculator(name1, height_m1, weight_kg1)
result2 = bmi_calculator(name2, height_m2, weight_kg2)
result3 = bmi_calculator(name1, height_m1, weight_kg3)

print(result1)
print(result2)
print(result3)
```

output:

```
117.912
505.4
338.8
Fahadis overweight
Rardois overweight
Billyis overweight
```

Edit: the BMI formula seems to be incorrect (Formula: `weight (kg) / [height (m)]**2` https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/index.html#Interpreted), yielding the incorrect output values, but I'll leave that to you as a math exercise.

Hopefully this explains the corrections. Feel free to comment if you need further clarification.